# Excel formula to manipulate cell text

Tags: excel-formula, lambda, substitution, textjoin, filterxml

I have this text value in an excel cell:

```
,!Đ49,-,Đ50*,!Đ173,-,Đ174*,Đ197,-,!Đ198,-,Đ199*,Đ264,!Đ314,-,Đ315*,Đ330,
```

I need to manipulate it to reach the following result withotu VBA:

```
,Đ49,-,Đ50,Đ173,-,Đ174,Đ197,-,Đ199,Đ264,Đ314,-,Đ315,Đ330,
```

I tried many ways, like LAMBDA, and multiple substitutes, but I am failed.

The closes result I was able to get to it is using FILTERXML as this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10); 1;  "," & FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E3; "!"; "<r>"); "*"; "</r>") & "</s></t>"; "//r"))&","
```

resulting this:

```
,Đ49,-,Đ50,Đ173,-,Đ174,Đ198,-,Đ199,Đ314,-,Đ315,
```

**PROBLEMS are compared to desired result:**

,Đ49,-,Đ50,Đ173,-,Đ174,**Đ197,-,Đ199**,**Đ264**,Đ314,-,Đ315,**Đ330**,

- When 'series' contains more than 2 elements, first ignored, in this case:
  it gives: 198-199 instead of 197-199
- Since I am filtering parts between '!' and '*' the rest elements gets chopped of, in this case:
  missing: 264 and 330

**Could anybody help me please with a concrete help? Very much appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work with your sample text:

```
=","&TEXTJOIN(","; TRUE; TEXTSPLIT(
LET(
   arr; TEXTSPLIT(E3; ",-,");
   TEXTJOIN(",-,"; TRUE; FILTER(arr; ISNUMBER(FIND(","; arr))))
); {"*,!";"*,";",!";","}))&","
```

It is dependent on the following conditions:

1. the text value always begins and ends with a comma (,)
2. asterisks only appear before a comma (*,)
3. exclamation points only appear after a comma (,!)

[image: textjoin_textsplit.png]

Cheers!